# ¿Porque mi dialog de Jquery no aparece cuando le doy click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, alertdialog

Estoy intentando hacer un dialogo de confirmacion que pasa cuando le das click al link de elimar se despliega el dialogo de ¿Estas seguro que quieres eliminar la app? Pero por alguna razon no me aparece.

Este es mi html.

```
<a class="link_pointer" id="delete_link_{{ store_app.id }}"><img src="/static/img/icon_tool_close.gif" alt='Eliminar Colección' title='Eliminar Colección'></a>

<div id="dialog_remove_col" class="kard" title="¡Advertencia!">
    <p>¿Estás seguro de que quieres eliminar tu aplicacion?</p>
</div>
```

y este es mi archivo javascript:

```
function delete_kapps_form(selector, content){
$('#dialog_remove_col').dialog({
    autoOpen: false, 
          resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Eliminar': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            send_request("/coleccion/eliminar/"+$(this).attr("to_delete")+"/", "", "POST", refresh_col_list);
        },
        Cancelar: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');

        }
    }
      });       
$('a[id*=delete_link_]').click(function(){
    var id_col = $(this).attr('id').replace('delete_link_', ''); 
    $("#dialog_remove_col").attr("to_delete", id_col);
    open_dialog_remove_col(id_col);
});
}

$functions['delete_kapps_form'] = delete_kapps_form;

function open_dialog_remove_col(id_col){
$("#dialog_remove_col").dialog('open');
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Puedes ver en la consola si está accediendo a la función open_dialog_remove_col(id_col){ } , también podrías intentar con $("#dialog_remove_col").show(); en lugar de .dialog('open')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya solucione mi problema lo que era es que el jquery se estaba cargando antes que el for de Django lo soluciones utlizando:

```
function enable_store_kapps_envents(selector, content){
$('body').on('click', selector, function(){

    $('#dialog_remove_kapp').dialog({
        autoOpen: true, 
        resizable: false,
        height:180,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Eliminar': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                send_request("/tienda/configurar/kapps/eliminar/"+$(this).attr("to_delete")+"/", "", "POST");
            },
            Cancelar: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    })

});    
}

$functions['enable_store_kapps_envents'] = enable_store_kapps_envents;
```